# Checkpoint Multi-Factor Authentication

Tags: freeradius

Anybody have experience setting up multi-factor authentication on the Checkpoint SmartDashboard and the Gaia login?

Been looking at WiKID and FreeRADIUS setups, but haven't really managed to make them work.

Answer (score 1):

Multi-factor with FreeRADIUS is always a custom solution.

I wouldn't try this with anything earlier than FreeRADIUS v3.0.x.

Your main tools are the RADIUS `Access-Challenge` packet which signals to the NAS that more information is required, the `State` RADIUS attribute which links together multiple requests and responses, and the `&session-state:` list, which is used to store information that needs to persist across multiple Access-Request/Access-Challenge rounds.

Your RADIUS client also needs to explicitly support MFA, by presenting the user with multiple prompts for collecting additional credentials.

If you can provide a bit more information about what factors your using, and what RADIUS client you're using I'll add more content to this answer.

Comment: Hi thanks for the answering. So far I have been using this PDF guide  https://community.checkpoint.com/t5/General-Topics/MFA-with-Google-Authenticator/td-p/39456. 

I'm trying to rebuild this setup as of writing since I may have messed up the previous one I've been using.

Comment: Sorry about the formatting.